# Rust use of moved value

Tags: rust

When using below function:

```
fn factors(number: &BigInt) -> Vec<BigInt> {
    let mut n = number.clone();
    let mut i: BigInt = ToBigInt::to_bigint(&2).unwrap();
    let mut factors = Vec::<BigInt>::new();

    while i * i <= n {
        if (n % i) == ToBigInt::to_bigint(&1).unwrap() {
            i = i + ToBigInt::to_bigint(&1).unwrap();
        }
        else {
            n = n/i as BigInt;
            factors.push(i);
        }
        i = i + ToBigInt::to_bigint(&1).unwrap();
    }
    if n > i {
        factors.push(n);
    }
    factors
}
```

I get moved value errors for literally every time `i` or `n` is used, starting from the line with `while`, also in the `if`. I have read about borrowing, which I understand decently, but this thing I don't understand.
I am not "copying" the value at all, so I don't see anywhere were I could lose ownership of the variables.

Comment: What kind of type is BigInt? Which crate is it from?

Comment: ow, excuse me, it is from `num`. It is a big int, which is does not implement the `Copy` trait, since that would be very, very, very CPU time intensive. (I know I am copying it here too, I couldn't find a better solution for the life of me)

Comment: Ah no need for apologies, just wondered which types they were.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`Mul`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ops/trait.Mul.html) (and the other arithmetic operators) take the parameters by value, so `i * i` move the value `i` (this is not a problem for primitive numbers because they implement `Copy` - `BigInt` does not).

As `Mul` is implemented for (two) `&BigInt`, you can do the multiplication (and the other arithmetic operations)  with `&`:

```
use num::*;

fn factors(number: &BigInt) -> Vec<BigInt> {
    let mut n = number.clone();
    let mut i = BigInt::from(2);
    let mut factors = Vec::new();

    while &i * &i <= n {
        if (&n % &i) == BigInt::one() {
            i = i + BigInt::one();

        } else {
            n = n / &i;
            factors.push(i.clone());
        }
        i = i + BigInt::one();
    }
    if n > i {
        factors.push(n);
    }
    factors
}
```

Note that I also made some simplifications, like omitting the type on `Vec::new` and using `BigInt::from` (cannot fail).

Comment: That makes sense. What is BigInt::one() contained in, since for some reason Rust can't find it... EDIT: found it, it is spelled with a capital to include it for whatever reason

Comment: You have to import [`num::One`](http://rust-num.github.io/num/num/trait.One.html)

Comment: @Epse `num::One` is a trait, so is capitalized. The trait includes a function, `One::one`, which is only accessible for trait implementers if the trait is also visible.

Answer (score 4):

Remember that operators in Rust are just syntactic sugar for function calls.

`a + b` translates to `a.add(b)`.

Primitive types such as `i32` implement the trait `Copy`. Thus, they can be copied into such an add function and do not need to be moved.

I assume the `BigInt` type you are working with does not implement this trait.
Therefore, in every binary operation you are moving the values.